# How to tell git to (1) ignore changes and (2) abandon managing commited file

Tags: git

Lets assume I have config file with secret api keys.

I can commit the template of this config file with api keys changed to something like `{put your api key here}`, so actual keys won't go to the repo.

Now, while developing I can put production api keys in that config file and do:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged my.config
```

... to tell git to pretend that there were no changes in config file and do both production builds with api keys in place and not worry about commiting those keys into repo by accident.

However, when I do something like:

```
git reset --hard
```

... git reverts my config file to the state that is commited in repo.

How can I avoid this, i.e. is there a way to tell git something like "See this file? DO NOT TOUCH IT!".

Any other approaches on solving this problem are welcomed.

Comment: I'd just put the secrets in an ignored config file, and commit e.g. a `.template` file for the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your template of your config file to be really template, something like `config.sample`.

Also provide install script which will ask user questions and generate or ask user to provide real working `config` file.

This way, you don't have to constantly depend on git hacks.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution (no Git magic) is to commit a file named something like `apikeys.txt.template`, then put `apikeys.txt` in the `.gitignore`. Then tell your users to fill in the `apikeys.txt` based on the template and/or offer a script that does this for them.